# Split an integer and find the largest sum C++

Tags: c++

I'm starting learning C++ on my own and I'm confused with one assignment which I'm trying to complete. User shoud type in natural numbers as long as he wants until he types in 0. After that my program should find the largest sum of digits which were typed and print it out. It shoud also print out a number from which it took the sum.
Here is what I tried to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int input = 0;
    int digit;
    int sum = 0;
    int largest = 0;

    do
    {
        cout << "enter a natural number (0 if done): " << flush;
        cin >> input;

        while (input > 0)
        {
            digit = input % 10;
            sum = sum + digit;
            input = input / 10;
        }
        if (sum > largest)
            largest = sum;  

    } while (input);

    cout << "Max sum of digits was " << largest << "for" << endl;
}
```

When I'm running the programm it counts sum of digits from only first typed in number and stop working. When I take `while (input > 0)` away, it makes a loop, but doesn't count digits. 
I'll be very grateful for help and explanation.
P.S. Sorry for my English, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: What's a "digest sum"?

Comment: When you exit the `while(input > 0)` loop, `input == 0` (because the `input = input / 10;` of the last iteration will return 0). Therefore, when you hit `} while (input);` the condition is `false` and you break from the outer `do {..} while` loop from its first iteration. That's why you get you get only `1` iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have three problems here:

1 - You are trying to use a variable that you essentially set to zero in your while loop

2 - You seem to be looking for the input that is for the largest sum

3 - You are not resetting your sum variable for each input

The solution for the first problem is to "backup" the input into another variable before modifying it and using that variable for the while loop.

That also allows for you to get what the largest number inputted is and store it.

```
int input = 0;
int inputBackup = 0;
int digit;
int sum = 0;
int largest = 0;
int largestInput = 0;
```

To add in the `inputBackup` variable, put it after the `cin`.

Then set the `largestInput` in your `sum > largest` if statement to set the `largestInput` if it is the largest.

```
cout << "enter a natural number (0 if done): " << flush;
cin >> input;

inputBackup = input;// This line
sum = 0;            // and this line

while (input > 0)
{
    digit = input % 10;
    sum = sum + digit;
    input = input / 10;
}
if (sum > largest)
{
    largest = sum;
    largestInput = inputBackup;// Store largest input
}
```

Then change `while(input)` to `while(inputBackup)` to check the `inputBackup` variable instead of the `input` one.

Change your `cout` to be like this to add the `largestInput` variable into it

```
cout << "Max sum of digits was " << largest << " for " << largestInput << endl;
```

And your code should be fixed!

Happy Coding!

Comment: This is great! Thanks you a lot))

Comment: No problem! I just saw that you seemed to have more questions in the question than the initial one that you had said

Answer (score 2):

```
do
{
    cout << "enter a natural number (0 if done): " << flush;
    cin >> input;
    //more code
} while (input);
```

To make this work correctly, `input` may not change between the `cin` and the loop condition.

But

```
while (input > 0) {
    digit = input % 10;
    sum = sum + digit;
    input = input / 10;
}
```

does change `input`.

Replace it with something like

```
int input2 = input;
while (input2 > 0) {
    digit = input2 % 10;
    sum = sum + digit;
    input2 = input2 / 10;
}
```

Comment: It counts the sum of all digits, but I still need the sum of every number I typed in :(

Answer (score 1):

Try that instead

If we do not zero `sum` value, it accumulate sum of all input digits and the sum will always be larger than than `largest` value, bacause it stores `largest + sum` of current values digits. So, if we zero `sum` value it only contains sum of digits of current input and can be simple compared with previous one wich was `largest`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;



int main() {

    int input = 0;
    int digit;
    int sum = 0;
    int largest = 0;

    do
    {
        while (input > 0) {
            digit = input % 10;
            sum = sum + digit;
            input = input / 10;
            }
                if (sum > largest)
                    largest = sum;

        sum = 0; // set to 0 current sum

        cout << "enter a natural number (0 if done): " << flush;
        cin >> input;

    } while (input);

   cout << "Max sum of digits was " << largest << " for" << endl;

   _getch();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can simply replace your input code to the end of the loop, it will work properly because you initialize input variable with 0 and because of that your inner loop will be ignored.

Comment: It works better, but not in the way I needed. Now it counts the sum of all typed in digits, but I need the sum of digits of every number. And after that, program should choose the biggest sum. Maybe you can recommend how to do this?

Comment: Yeees!! It works. Thank you so much!! Can you explain me in a couple words why did sum = 0; change everything?

Answer (score 1):

In this part:

```
while (input > 0) {
  digit = input % 10;
  sum = sum + digit;
  input = input / 10;
}
```

while input is not zero it'll repeat, so when get out the loop the value of input is 0. Use a auxiliary variable or enclose this code on a function:

```
 int getDigitsSum(int input) {
      while (input > 0) {
        digit = input % 10;
        sum = sum + digit;
        input = input / 10;
      }
      return sum;
 }
```

Comment: you forget return sum